# How to make a python program which compresses a text file with several sentences? and recreates full text?

Tags: python

I came up with this, but how would I shorten this down subtantially for the conventional python shell.

```
import zlib, sys, time, base64, pymsgbox, ttk
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
import Tkinter as tk


def getPath():
    path = askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Text Files", (".txt")), ("Text", '.txt'), ('All', '*')], )
    return path


def compress():
    text = open(getPath(), 'r').read()
    realSize = 'Raw size :' + str(sys.getsizeof(text))
    print(realSize)
    comperesed = base64.b64encode(zlib.compress(text, 9))
    compressedSize = 'Raw size :' + str(sys.getsizeof(comperesed))
    print(compressedSize)
    compressedFile = pymsgbox.prompt('Compressd File Name:') + '.txt'
    encoded = open(compressedFile, 'a')
    encoded.write(comperesed)
    encoded.close()


def decompress():
    readFile = open(getPath(), 'r').read()
    decompressed = zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode(readFile))
    decompressedFile = pymsgbox.prompt('Decompressd File Name:') + '.txt'
    decoded = open(decompressedFile, 'a')
    decoded.write(decompressed)
    decoded.close()


def gui():
    # Make Message
    pymsgbox.alert('Welcome', 'Compressing and Decompressing')
    win = tk.Tk()
    win.title("Compressing and Decompressing")
    aLabel = ttk.Label(win, text="Compress")
    aLabel.grid(column=0, row=0)
    aLabel = ttk.Label(win, text="Decompress")
    aLabel.grid(column=0, row=1)
    action = ttk.Button(win, text="Convert", command=compress)
    action.grid(column=1, row=0)
    action = ttk.Button(win, text="Convert", command=decompress)
    action.grid(column=1, row=1)
    win.mainloop()


gui()
```

Comment: please read your question: does it make sense as is? No. Is the formatting unreadable and broken? yes. Is the question answerable ? No. Is there really a question? No.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! To get the most out of the site it is important to ask good questions. A guide to asking questions is at: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: In particular, I recommend reading about [minimal examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

If I undestand the question correctly you want to just run the compress and decompress functions from a python shell.

```
import zlib, sys, base64

def compress(decompressedFile, compressedFile):
    text = open(decompressedFile, 'r').read()
    realSize = 'Raw size :' + str(sys.getsizeof(text))
    print(realSize)
    comperesed = base64.b64encode(zlib.compress(text, 9))
    compressedSize = 'Raw size :' + str(sys.getsizeof(comperesed))
    print(compressedSize)
    encoded = open(compressedFile, 'a')
    encoded.write(comperesed)
    encoded.close()


def decompress(compressedFile, decompressedFile):
    readFile = open(compressedFile, 'r').read()
    decompressed = zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode(readFile))
    decoded = open(decompressedFile, 'a')
    decoded.write(decompressed)
    decoded.close()
```

I saved this file as test554.py and used:

```
>>> import test554
>>> test554.compress("testuncompress.txt", "testuncompress2.txt")
Raw size :115
Raw size :129
>>> test554.decompress("testuncompress2.txt", "testuncompress3.txt")
```

This first compressed the testuncompress.txt file to testuncompress2.txt then decompressed testuncompress2.txt to testuncompress3.txt.